# How do I capture a live IP Camera feed (eg: http://61.60.112.230/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=938427) to python application?

Tags: python, opencv, camera, video-streaming

I need to perform image recognition thing on real time camera feed. The video is embedded in shtml hosted on a IP. How do I access the video and process things using openCV.

Comment: Windows or Linux? Some time ago I used Gstreamer for this and compiled OpenCV with Gstreamer support.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is very broad. Please try to conentrate on a specific problem you have implementing a solution. Have a look at our guide [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and it will be much more likely that you get a useful answer.

Comment: Using a windows machine

Comment: I will refresh my knowledge regarding this and let you know in few hours (if I success).

Comment: Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

First,you need to find the actual path to camera stream. It is mjpeg or rtsp stream. Use developer option in this page to find the stream, like `http://ip/video.mjpg` or `rtsp://ip/live.sdp`. When you find the stream url,create python script which will use stream like `capture = cv2.VideoCapture(stream_url)`. But,as noticed,this is too broad which mean you are asking for full tutorial. This is some directions,and when you have some code,ask a question about issues with your code and you'll get an answer.